# Java Socket not Receiving connection

Tags: java, ios, swift, sockets

So I have made several similar simple Java servers and clients. They work fine when I run them from Eclipse or as far I can say from same computer.

The moment I send client program to other computer, they can't bind.

As well, I made Swift app for iOS and tried to reach the server from phone but to no avail.

Now, this is my sample code, it's just bare bones, and it still doesn't work. Is there some problem with problem with Firewall that I need to address? I run MacBookPro 2010, OS Sierra 10.12 beta. Eclipse is verified in Firewall though.

```
public class BasicServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ServerSocket sam = null;
        Socket bob = null;
        try {
            sam = new ServerSocket(1025);
            System.out.println("Server is Cheking acceptance");
            bob = sam.accept();
            if (bob != null) {
                System.out.println("\nSystem Accepted");
            }
            System.out.println("\nClosing Server...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error on server side of type: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally {
            try {
            sam.close();
            bob.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Socket on Finally had encountered an Error:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this one works from Eclipse

```
public class TransServer {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.out.println("Action Done");


        try {

            Socket sam = new Socket("some IPv6", 1025);
            System.out.println("Done...");
            if (sam.isConnected()) {
                System.out.print("Connected!");
            }

            sam.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error Occoured: " + e);
        } 

    }

}
```

and this is swift code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let serverIP = "some IPv6"

    @IBOutlet weak var textOutlet: UITextView!

    @IBAction func connectAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // textOutlet.title = ""
        connectToServer()
    }

    private func connectToServer() {
        let mySocket = TCPClient(address: serverIP, port: 1025)

        let connectResult = mySocket.connect(timeout: 2)

        switch connectResult {
        case .failure(let e):
            textOutlet.text = "We received an error: \(e.localizedDescription)"
        case .success:
            textOutlet.text = "We have successfuly established a Connection to server!"
        }

        mySocket.close()

        textOutlet.text.append("\nWe have closed the Socket")

    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you find `serverIP`? The computers / device has to be on the same network. On macOS, you can find the IP in Network Preferences...

Comment: I type it on google and it shows up, like "my ip"... I want to access the server both from different devices and different ip's... like my friend from different state should be able to send a request to server...

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was getting bad IP address from Google and other web services. When I looked at my network properties I found my real address and when I used that one everything worked fine...

Comment: The IP that you see in Network Preferences is you "private" IP address. It is only usable for devices within the same network. The IP that you see on Google is the "public" IP -- you will need it if you want your server to be accessible by, say, your friend on another continent. Public IP is not mapped to private IP by default; you need to configure Network Address Translation (NAT) to do that.